# set bootPassword for derby database at runtime using hibernate

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, derby

I use Hibernate and Derby.

I have a hibernate.cfg.xml and all I did for working with db waas to get a Session :

```
  return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure( "files/hibernate.cfg.xml"   ).buildSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
```

my hibernate.cfg.xml containes

```
   <property name="connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</property>
   <property name="connection.url">jdbc:derby:crmdb;create=true</property>
```

and some other properties and mappings for entity classes.

now I want to set dataEncryption for derby db and bootPassword at runtime.

I changed hibernate.cfg.xml :

```
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:derby:crmdb;create=true;dataEncryption=true;bootPassword=myPass</property>
```

and everything was ok.

Now I want to set bootPassword at runtime, e.x.by reading from an environment variable. that´s the problem! 
when I delete "connection.url" from hibernate.cfg.xml and trying to set it inside my code, this error ocurres :

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
```

and if I delete only bootPassword, it can not connect to db.

any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It resolved !

I should set "hibernate.connection.url" instead of "connection.url" !

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the configuration before building the sessionFactory:

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
    if(sessionFactory==null){
        Configuration configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure( "files/hibernate.cfg.xml"   );
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:derby:crmdb;create=true;dataEncryption=true;bootPassword="+password);
        configuration.configure();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Other remark : you must avoid to recreate a new SessionFactory everytime (it take a lot of time, consume lot of resources and it's useless). i.e. You must create one sessionFactory for each bootPassword (since it's the only dynamic part) and if you only have one bootPassword - i.e. one single DB - then your sessionFactory can/must be a singleton.

[ref](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: @ref Thanks very much for answer and hint about sessionFactory. I updated my code for sessionFactory.but the problem for connection already exists.It seems that configuration doesn´t accept setProperty after reading a cfg.xml file.

Comment: sorry... There was errors in my code : 1. property must be prefixed by `hibernate.` 2. need to call `configure()` after updating the property. (The post is updated)

Comment: thanks. I don´t think calling configure() again be ok. because it overwrites all setting again.